# how do I change default editor for sudo vipw from "vi" to "vim" by tcsh in FreeBSD

Tags: editor, sudo, freebsd, tcsh

When I use command `sudo vipw` to edit my password file, It's always use vi as editor. I don't like this very much and want to change it to vim.

I already tried:
Add `export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/vim` in `/etc/profile`.
But shell told me "export: Command not found". I thought the reason is export is built-in function only in `bash`. And I don't want to change my shell.

Add`EDITOR=/usr/lcoal/bin/vim` in default block of `/etc/login.conf`
Add `setenv EDITOR vim` in `/root/.cshrc`, `/.cshrc`, `~/.cshrc`

All above didn't work at all.
I have google for hours but could not find anything help.

Comment: The question probably belongs on unix.SE, but `profile` and `login.conf` are the wrong files for `tcsh` - your `.cshrc` changes should work though. Can you see your new EDITOR value when you use `setenv` at the command line?

Comment: Yes, after I use `setenv EDITOR vi`, I can see the value of EDITOR is vi by `printenv`

Comment: By the way, when I'm using root account, `vipw` will use `vim` as editor.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `sudo`, but it probably sanitises the environment. You should check its man page to ensure that the EDITOR variable is set or inherited correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your /etc/sudoers file doesn't keep your EDITOR environment variable.

I personally have an /etc/sudoers.d/local file, something like

```
# We don't need to worry about wheel users breaking in to get root access because they already have it.
Defaults:%wheel env_keep+="HOME EDITOR",!set_home,shell_noargs
```

I'm not sure why this isn't the default, since wheel users have already been given full access.  But it's apparently prevailing wisdom to continue hassling them.

Note: If you're using an older /etc/sudoers file that doesn't support an /etc/sudoers.d directory, these lines can be dropped in there... or you could add `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` as the last line of your /etc/sudoers file to enable an /etc/sudoers.d directory.  Um, yes, the `#` is a required part of that line, because someone thought it was important for that directive to look like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `root` user `/root/.chsrc`:

```
setenv EDITOR  vim
```

or to set it globally to all users using shell `tcsh/csh` add it in `/etc/csh.cshrc`

From the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcsh(1)):

```
A login shell begins by executing commands from the system files /etc/csh.cshrc  
and /etc/csh.login. It then executes commands from files in the  user's  home directory:
first  ~/.tcshrc or, if ~/.tcshrc is not found, ~/.cshrc ...

Non-login  shells read only /etc/csh.cshrc and ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc on startup.
```

Also verify [vim](https://www.freshports.org/editors/vim-console/) is installed since is not by default, you could try:

```
pkg install vim-console
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an empty file called `.selected_editor` in `$HOME` (`/root`).
Remove it and the next call to `vipw` will ask you to select the editor.

Answer (score 0):

setting the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variable is the key.
if you don't want to go to the trouble of modifying config files (which is indeed the long term solution) then you could `sudo su -` to get to the root prompt and then you could `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` before running `vipw`

Comment: Why lower case?